# Ckeditor find by class with custom config

Tags: symfony, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I'm confused how can I make ckeditor to find by class

```
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'chillair_sitebundle_pagetype[content]', {
        filebrowserBrowseUrl : '{{ ['http://', app.request.host, asset('libraries/elfinder/elfinder.html')]|join }}',
    });
</script>
```

The goal is to make replace by class
But findAll don't support custom config 
I need config in a page becouse it's important twig to render variables like host and asset function, so I can't movie config to config.js